# php, html, change a select to selective after writeing first word and so on

Tags: javascript, php, html

this is the select.

```
<select name='select_name'>
     <option value='1'>one</option>
     <option value='2'>tow</option>
     <option value='3'>three</option>
     <option value='4'>fore</option>
    //here i have more then 300 select which i will fetch from database
</select>
```

i want to change it input so when i write the first later it fetch me the match items and so on if the secound later it match as i write. if is possible please write me hint so i could save my time.

for example if i write **(t)**  it will show me

```
tow
three
```

regards

Comment: By default, select dropdowns take you to the point where you're typing.   It's a fair bit of work to replace that functionality, so why try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a **combo box**. If you don't want to write it from scratch, you could use a plugin instead.

In this example is [**`Select2 Plugin:`**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<select name='select_name' style="width:300px">
    <option value='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
    <option value='3'>three</option>
    <option value='4'>four</option>
    <option value='5'>five</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name="select_name"]').select2();
});
</script>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/idGHBj)